# Is there a hook before the user is authenticated?

Tags: hooks, login

I'm looking for a hook that can be used before WP reads the DB to authenticate the user's login credentials, but can't seem to find one anywhere. Does one exist?

I tried `add_filter/action('authenticate', 'customcode', 30, 3)`, but this seems to execute as soon as the `wp-login.php` page is requested, rather than after the user hits login and the username/password is `POST`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, turns out `add_filter/action('authenticate', 'customcode', 30, 3)` was what I was looking for...

The problem was, I had the priority too low so whatever response I was creating with my custom code was over-ridden by the other filters.

So dumping `global $wp_filter['authenticate']` I could see the following filters:

```
20, wp_authenticate_username_password
30, wp_authenticate_cookie
99, wp_authenticate_spam_check
```

By changing the priority to 100 (or higher), I could do the overriding instead and create the response I wanted for handling the login credentials submitted via the login page.

Comment: There's only two arguments  for `customcode` so it should be `add_action('authenticate', 'customcode', 30, 2)`. The 3 is confusing.

Comment: `authenticate` should be filter, i believe, https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the code for `wp-login.php` [both the `login` case and the default case](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-login.php#L777) run [`wp_signon()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-login.php#L806). The reason, so it seems to me, is to manage cases where a user already has a valid cookie for the site. So I don't think there is a hook that fires only upon login, but it is pretty easy to compensate. The first hook along that login path and before authentication is the action hook `wp_authenticate` not `authenticate` (though that is a valid hook).

```
function customcode($username, $password ) {
  if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    // your code
  }
}
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'customcode', 30, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks.This kind of works too except any responses returned by the `authenticate` filters ends up overriding any returned by `wp_authenticate` so, not quite what I was looking for - just me phrasing the question wrong though =/